# Is there some deep significance to Dharma Initiative Station's logos?

Tags: analysis, lost

In *Lost*, we got to know that the Dharma Initiative has so many different stations and each of them have unique logos. Do those logos have some deeper meaning or are they just random?

[image]

I always thought that they are related to Hinduism and I even confused Hydra symbol with [Shesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shesha), as a few of the logos do have religious significance.

The whole show's theme was *belief vs science* and it made me think that a science research center having a religious logo will have some deeper significance. Am I right?

Comment: ["The DHARMA Initiative is represented by a series of distinct eight-sided logos, based on the traditional Taoist Bagua or pa kua ("eight trigrams" in Chinese)"](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/DHARMA_logos)

Comment: In general, the logos are the same "I-Chings" for lack of a better word (sorry). Only the center seems to change, meaning the border can probably be removed from the equation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lined, octogonal part of the logo is influenced by ancient Chinese designs.

From [Lostpedia](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/DHARMA_logos#I_Ching):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Each interior image pretty directly matches up to the Station or profession it represents.

For example:

[image]

[The Swan](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Swan) logo is of a swan.

[image]

[The Staff](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Staff) logo is of the medically-relevant [Caduceus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caduceus).

[image]

[The Looking Glass](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Looking_Glass) logo is of a white rabbit, a reference to the White Rabbit character from the novel *[Through the Looking-Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass)*.

---

More information can be read on the page linked above.